# Hide/Unhide custom menu item under standard menu item based on transactions

Tags: abap

I have a custom menu item created under system menu in the menu bar. I want the menu item to be displayed only in case of certain transactions.

The transactions are configured for my business scenario.

I tried the following:

1) Assigning a switch to the custom menu item under system menu in menu painter would hide/unhide it across all the transactions depending on whether the switch is active or not.
Also checked whether switch can be assigned set of transactions rather than a package. No luck.

2) Checked whether the code is hitting the statement set pf status. It's just hitting the set pf status for the other menu items like Goto and Edit. So don't know how exactly the system and help menu options are being populated. If I know exactly the working that is the common logic executed here, then I can possibly populate the custom menu item by reading the configuration of transactions.

3) Transaction variants is another option. But here too we do not have access to system and help menu options. Plus if it works, it would be not a generic solution as I will have to create transaction variant for all the transactions.

Comment: As you correctly analyzed, options 1 and 2 are not possible, and only the option 3 is left to you (GuiXT "pushbutton" which triggers the function code you have defined in the System menu). No other solution.

Comment: How did you implement this custom menu? Show the code